# JquerySVG elements get clipped at a certain point, how to fix this?

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I am creating some rectangles using jQuerySVG 1.5, and I am having an issue where I have variable data for `x`, `y`, `w` and `h`.  I am looking to increase the scale of my elements, so I have a variable I am multiplying by.  When I have set the `scale` to `2`, the rectangles print fine, but when I set it to `3`, some of them get cut off, and the rest are "hidden" behind an element.

I saw this problem before when I was messing around.  To fix it I would set the CSS `width` and `height` to the width and height of my element.

i.e.,

```
$('#svg').css({ width: "100px", height: "100px", position: "absolute"});
```

For some reason it isn't working this time.  I have tried adding the `div`s I create for my SVG into another `div` it doesn't work, nor does setting the body height to a large number like 1000, or 10000 does it fix this issue.

I've also noticed if I make the rectangles really big, and then zoom with google chrome that depending on my zoom % amount it will cut off more of less of the rectangles.

Here are some pictures that illustrate my issue:

http://imageshack.com/a/img540/7610/9KrAp3.png

Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  var scale = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var svg = document.createElement("div");
    svg.id = 'svg' + i;
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
    $('#svg' + i).svg();
    var svgE = $('#svg' + i).svg('get');
    svgE.rect(x,y,w,h, {
        stroke: 'lightblue',
        strokeWidth: 0.5
      });

    $('#svg' + i).css({
      position: "absolute"
    });
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You'll have to change the `width`, `height` and `viewPort` of the `svg` elements using JavaScript. For Example: `document.getElementById('id-of-the-svg').setAtrribute('width', 'depends-on-your-scale')`

Comment: or with jQuery: `$('id-of-svg').attr('width', '...')`

Comment: Sure, it will take some time as I have to grab all the JSON data and compact it for this example..  thank you very much for the edits :)..

Edit:  Okay will check that out... Thanks :).

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the viewport is, and what sort of values i'm looking to put for it?  I'm looking all over Google and not really finding anything besides "meta viewport..." Thank you :)

Comment: `viewPort="x y width height"` --------> where `x` and `y` defines the top-left corner and `width` and `height` defines the width and height of the visible area. For example if `x` and `y` were `1`; and `width` and `height` were `100`, then the `x` and `y` values would be from `1 - 100`. Alltogether, your `svg` element should look like --------> `<svg width="100" height="100" viewPort="1 1 100 100">....</svg>`

Comment: Well the thing is, is this for some main element, or for all of my elements?  It seems to just cut off all of my elements regardless of which element it is at some sort of point.  i.e., it cuts off at 600x400  If I had 1 element, or 500, whatever crosses that line will go over.

also for future reference how would I set this up?        $('#svg'+i).attr('width',  ...);
        $('#svg'+i).attr('height', ...);
        $('#svg'+i).attr('viewport-x', ...);
        $('#svg'+i).attr('viewport-y', ...);
        $('#svg'+i).attr('viewport-width',...);
        $('#svg'+i).attr('viewport-height',...);

Comment: Hmmmm I really need to see the live code. If you can't set up a Fiddle, could you upload it to your server and give me a link?

Comment: Setting up the fiddle now, taking awhile, sorry :P.  It's late here I might pass out and finish tomorrow.

Comment: Is there anything special i need to add for jquerySVG to work Fiddle isn't liking my code... sorry it's taking so long, I was trying to get a full example, and realized I could just make a small example, plus this is my first time using it :p.

I think I will continue this tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Ended up finding a result on my own, posted below, thanks for the help much appreciated :).

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll still get a notification towards this chip, but this entire issue is still happening, and it's annoying :P.

More issues formed from one issue (damn Alien Queen...)


Here is my full issue with examples from the GitHub

I've emailed the owner so I hope he can look at this, because it's extremely confusing what's going on.....


Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: ugh I failed to post the github link... which is here.


https://github.com/kbwood/svg/issues/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem.

Basically I have 1 div per element, so I can interact with each element individually.  This means I have to use 0,0 as my x,y within the div, and set my div's location to place the items properly.

This means I needed to get rid of x,y with my rectangle, and use it with left, and top as css positioning instead.

```
$('#svg').css({width: width, height: height, position: "absolute", left:x, top: y});
```

I am also adding draggable to these svg rectangles     `$( "#svg"+i ).draggable({ snap: true });`

So I need each element to be contained within the div properly, or else I will be snapping to random areas of the screen.

What happens is, for some reason, the svg is setting the width of my viewport to be 3000, but no height at all.  I'm not sure what the viewport height is, but after awhile it breaks.

To do this I tried changing the viewport, and the viewbox with `svg.configure()`, with no luck.  However if I try setting "width and height" of my SVG element, it works.  Apparently this is setting the ViewPort's width and height directly, so I'm not sure why "

So the full code to get what I need working is.

```
    var svg = document.createElement("div");

    svg.id = 'svg';       
    document.body.appendChild(svg);

    $('#svg').svg();


    var svgE = $('svg').svg('get'); 
    svgE.configure({width: width, height: height, true);   
//According to the docs, the boolean at the end is ------ 

//clear (boolean, optional) is true to remove existing attributes first,
 //or false (default) to add to what is already there.
//in my case I want to rewrite everything.


 svgE.rect(0,0,data.width, height); //can also add other settings like fill within the rect
 // faceE.rect(0,0, width, height,{fill: color, stroke: color, strokeWidth: 1});

$( '#svg').draggable({ snap: true});
$('#svg').css({position:"absolute", left: x, top: y});
```

More information on SVG ViewPort and ViewBox can be found here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html

I hope anyone who has issues with be helped by this.